# Evaluating a limit with sin and tan in the question

Tags: calculus

Evaluate $$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{\tan 5x}$$

How do I start this? I thought maybe I needed to manipulate the equation into:

$\displaystyle \frac{\sin 0}{1} \cdot \frac{\cos 0}{\sin 0}$ so the sin's cancel with each other? And then I could work with the cos's?

Answer (score 1):

What are you allowed to use? Hint:multiply the numerator and denominator by $x$ and write $\tan 5 x =\frac{\sin 5 x}{\cos 5x}$. Recall $\frac{\sin x}{x} \to 1 $ as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's not that easy as you said. Let's see the way we can solve it.
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{\sin(2x)}{\tan(5x)}$$
gives the undefined form $\frac{0}{0}$ because $\lim_{x→0}\tan 5x = 0$.

Thus, you can use the Hospital rule. We know that $\frac{d(\sin 2x)}{dx} = 2 \cos(2x)$ and $\frac{d(\tan 5x)}{dx} = 5 \sec^2(5x) = \frac{5}{\cos^2(5x)}$. Applying the Hospital rule will give you this limit to evaluate :
$$\lim_{x→0}\frac{2 \cos(2x)}{5 \sec^2(5x)} = \frac{2 \cos0}{5 \sec^20} = \frac{2}{5}$$
This is the result you wanted. Hope this help you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

$$\frac{\sin2x}{\tan5x}=\frac25\cdot\frac{\sin2x}{2x}\cdot\frac{5x}{\sin5x}\cdot\cos5x$$

and use the basic fact that

$$f(x)\xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}0\implies\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin f(x)}{f(x)}=1$$